# Added request description | AssertionError: expected [] to have a length above 0 but got 0?

Tags: json, api, postman

[image]

How I can solve this issue in post man tired documentation but couldn't find any useful resource please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs in the Student Expert training, when verifying whether you have completed all of the tasks that were requested. Specifically, it relates to this element of the **Get specific player** request:

> Before you continue with scripting, add a description to this
> request—the description will appear within the collection
> documentation, which you would use if you were e.g. publishing an API
> for public use. In the Postman app, at the top of this request tab, to
> the left of the request name, expand and and click to edit. Add a
> short description of the request (you can use markdown) and click
> **Save**. If you're using the web version, use the little documentation icon to the right of the request.

The test is looking at the **Get specific player** endpoint and checking whether a description has been set: `expected [description] to have a length above 0 but got 0`. If you add a description, save, and regenerate your public collection share link, the test will pass.

Comment: Thank I found the solution. Thank You!!